# Url auth using is username and password but both have a @ in have trie encoding still getting error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I need to auth my url ,send a username and password with it. What do you do if the username is youre email and youre password contains an @ aswell. Is there another method in doing this

I have tried  window.open("https://name:password@url"); and tried encoding everythin but get a string error, any siggesstions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you have to encode the username and password (encodeURI) then you can add it .I had the https in the url as well which is wrong, only one https